# Why menconder fps rate does not work?

Tags: video, frame-rate, mencoder, timelapse

I'm using mencoder to create a video out of some .png files. The problem is that the frame rate doesn't change, regardless of the -fps flag. The output video has different time lengths (in their properties), but the video's size and speed are always the same (regardless of the FPS chosen).

I just want to create a shorted video by using higher FPS rates. In short, a "time-lapse" of my original set of images. What am I doing wrong with mencoder? I'm using the following command:

```
mencoder mf://./IMG/images*.png -mf w=800:h=600:fps=20:type=png -ovc copy -oac copy -o video.avi
```

Comment: Why did you add the [tag:ffmpeg] tag? Are you open to a solution using ffmpeg instead?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: I was open to a solution using ffmpeg, but I've managed it quickly. The problem with mencoder is still open.